# rtl listview / arrow-l jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am moving all of my site to rtl ..

Now I need a little help with the arrow . how can I make it be to the left?

It's not working for me now ...

You can take a look at the site here

Also I have made a float right to the firstview thumbnails. And now the curve is at the right .. How can i make it go to the left?

thanks a lot

Comment: interesting site but I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you going into a little more detail?

Comment: i want the arrow to be left arrow and not right arrow .

Answer (score 1):

Button Icons: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

```
data-icon="arrow-l"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a little changes to the markup classes as following:

In the list items `li` :

Change the class from `ui-btn-icon-right` to `ui-btn-icon-left` .

Then within the `li` item :

search for the `span` with class `ui-icon-arrow-r` and change it to `ui-icon-arrow-l`

hope that was useful.